# Single ode combining two odes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can we combine two ODEs on a single independent variable $s$

$$ ds^2= dx^2+dy^2+dz^2,\quad\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+z=0$$

$$\quad f\left(\frac{d^2z}{dy^2},\frac{dz}{dy}\right)=0,  \, 
\quad  or \quad  \frac{d^2z}{dy^2} = g \left( \frac{dz}{dy} \right) \, $$

so that $x,y,z$ can be computed by an ODE in terms of $s?$ Maybe employing an intermediate substitution $dr^2= dx^2+dy^2? $ It is non-axisymmetric.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: From the second equation you have $z=a\cos x+b \sin x$ so $dz=(a\sin x-b\cos x)dx$. You can use it to eliminate $z$, but I don't know what else can be done.